# How do I check if a timestamp occured after the beginning of this month in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I need to select records in `MySQL 5.0.88` base on the following criteria:

```
timestamp_last_update must have been set after the beginning of the current month
```

I'm looking at `DateFormat` currently, but cannot get it to work properly.

Can someone provide some info on whether this can be done with MySQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should employ something like

```
 WHERE timestamp_last_update > CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') as DATE)
```

or

```
 WHERE timestamp_last_update >= CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-02') as DATE)
```

depending on the meaning of "*after the beginning of the current month*" (i.e., whether the first day must count or not).

Comment: Thanks. Checking out both versions. First day of the months should be included. I have a feature that can be switched on/off by users and I need to check whether it has been switched on in the last month.